# how to sort 1000 of rows of html table using jquery or javascript fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I want to sort 1000 rows of an HTML table with JavaScript. It must sort textboxs, numbers, etc.

It works for 100 rows, but when the count of rows is bigger, it stop working and closes my application.

**Here its my code:**

```
  var Customtable;
    Customtable = document.getElementById('ExampleTable');
    //alert('custom table: ' + Customtable);

    function SortCustomTable(n, Isnormal) {
        var a, b, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
        switching = true;

        //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
        dir = "asc";
        /*Make a loop that will continue until
        no switching has been done:*/
        while (switching) {
            //start by saying: no switching is done:
            switching = false;

            //rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");

            /*Loop through all table rows (except the
            first, which contains table headers):*/

            var rowsCount = Customtable.rows.length - 1;
            for (i = 1; i < rowsCount ; i++) {

                //start by saying there should be no switching:
                shouldSwitch = false;
                /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
                one from current row and one from the next:*/

                //x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
                //y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
                /*check if the two rows should switch place,
                based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
                if (Customtable.rows[0].cells[n].className.includes("Input")) {

                    a = Customtable.rows[i].cells[n].getElementsByTagName("Input")[0].value
                    b = Customtable.rows[i + 1].cells[n].getElementsByTagName("Input")[0].value
                }
                else {
                    a = Customtable.rows[i].cells[n].textContent;
                    b = Customtable.rows[i + 1].cells[n].textContent;
                }

                if (Customtable.rows[0].cells[n].className.includes("Number")) {
                    x = Number(a)
                    y = Number(b)
                }
                else if (Customtable.rows[0].cells[n].className.includes("Text")) {
                    x = a.toLowerCase()
                    y = b.toLowerCase()
                }
                //else {
                //    x = (table.rows[i].cells[n]).innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                //    y = (table.rows[i + 1].cells[n]).innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                //}

                if (dir == "asc") {
                    if (a > b) {
                        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (dir == "desc") {
                    if (a < b) {
                        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (shouldSwitch) {
                /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
                and mark that a switch has been done:*/
                Customtable.rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(Customtable.rows[i + 1], Customtable.rows[i]);
                switching = true;
                //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
                switchcount++;
            } else {
                /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
                set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/

                if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc" && Isnormal == 1) {
                    dir = "desc";
                    switching = true;
                }
            }
        }
        alert('Done');
    }
</script>`
```

Comment: You'd better do it on the server side. JavaScript/Browser is not the place for long blocking operations. If you really have to do it in the browser then look into `web workers` to do it in the background.

Comment: Here's a sample for that : https://github.com/afshinm/50k

Answer (score 0):

As @BrahmaDev, mentioned, server side could be good (assuming you have access to it). Manipulating and updating the DOM is expensive, but if you are rendering the rows yourself (client-side template) from JSON data or something, then sorting JSON objects of 1000 rows should be fine and fast as long as you sort the dataset first and create the new rows as a concatenated string representing all the rows or DOM fragments and update the DOM in one shot.

Here's a link that explains what I'm talking about:
https://coderwall.com/p/o9ws2g/why-you-should-always-append-dom-elements-using-documentfragments